# Know from behind code what strings.xml i'm using in Android

Tags: android, multilingual

Can I know which file strings.xml in a multilanguage app I'm using from behind code?

Please show me an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your app language by update your resource configuration in run time. Like this code:

```
    Resources res=getResources();
    Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();
    Locale locale = new Locale("fr");//change to the France language
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    config.locale = locale;
    res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: That wasn't the question. But `Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;` could be used to read the current locale.